# open source tools for CNV analysis from illumina SNP array

Tags: r, microarray, illumina, cnv

What are the best open source tools to analyse copy number variation using Illumina SNP array data...preferably R based tools, but open to other languages as well.

I'm working with leukemia sample and I have Illumina scan data ..in IDAT/GTC file format and i wish to use tools that will utilise the BAF and LRR metrics.

Microarray platform used- Illumina infinium 850K cytoSNP (beadchip array)

Comment: What kind of analysis? What questions are you trying to answer? Should we assume human?

Comment: @terdon I am trying to do CNV analysis...to detect copy number gains/loss and copy neutral loss of heterozygosity.... I'm working on acute lymphoblastic leukemia samples

Comment: Yes, I mean what kind of analysis? The word "analysis" suggests you aren't just trying to detect CNVs, but need to _analyse_ them. Maybe annotate them? Classify them according to the ACMG criteria? If you just want to detect them, that's a different issue.

Comment: Maybe you can try karyoploteR. Great tutorial here: https://bernatgel.github.io/karyoploter_tutorial/